# stderr in the shell and a copy into log file

Tags: c#, wpf, process, stderr

I use the Process class to run pscp.exe (from Putty) in my WPF C# application like this:

```
Process p = new Process();
p.StartInfo.FileName = "pscp.exe";
p.StartInfo.Arguments = "-v -scp -pw xx toto@192.168.0.1:/path .";
p.Start();
p.WaitForExit();
```

The process opens a command prompt and exit correctly, it's ok.

Now, I would like to log in a file the stderr of the process, no problem, I use:

```
p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
```

and I print the stream in my file, but nothing is shown in the shell (it's ok this is a redirection).

My needs is to show the stderr in the shell AND copy it to my log file (no redirection, I wanted twice).

EDIT: A clear exemple that represent my need:
Imagine a WPF application with one button which call this function:

```
Process p = new Process();
p.StartInfo.FileName = "pscp.exe";
p.StartInfo.Arguments = "-v -scp -pw xx toto@192.168.0.1:/path .";
p.Start();
p.WaitForExit();
```

The process starts with a cmd prompt (print stdout + stderr in it) and at the same time stderr is printed in a log file.

Any idea to do this ?

Comment: Yes I have a method to do that. I forgot to say that my application is not a Console app but a WPF app. So, `Console.WriteLine()` is not adapted, I'm right ?

Comment: Yes, that's another matter entirely. `Log4Net` allows you to log to file *and* console at the same time, you might want to check it out. I'm removing my previous (now moot) comment.

Comment: Thanks, really nice tool, this could help me for other development, but sorry I don't understand how can Log4Net could solve my problem. How can I redirect stderr (`RedirectStandardError = true;`) without using `UseShellExecute = false;` which disable my prompt ?

Comment: Sorry, I got it backwards. I'll fiddle with some code and get back with an answer if I can make it work.

Comment: Up, did you make it work ?

Comment: The solution unfortunately eludes me

Answer (score 0):

You need to subscribe to the ErrorDataReceivedEvent

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.errordatareceived.aspx

```
Process p = new Process();
p.StartInfo.FileName = "pscp.exe";
p.StartInfo.Arguments = "-v -scp -pw xx toto@192.168.0.1:/path .";
p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
p.ErrorDataReceived += (o, e) => Console.Error.WriteLine(e.Data);
p.Start();
p.WaitForExit();
```

Comment: This don't solve my problem, I need to see the cmd prompt. To subscribe to the Event, the RedirectStandardError must be True. So this is a redirection not a copy of the stderr.

Comment: you can do many things and not just log, write to sdterr (shown in the code) and write to your log file.

Answer (score 0):

As described by Hylaean: First you prepare your Process object and register the event(s):

```
p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
p.ErrorDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(shell_ErrorDataReceived);
p.OutputDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(shell_OutputDataReceived);

shellOut = openWriter(outputFileName);   //  opens a StreamWriter
```

In the event handlers, you can do what you like with the stderr and stdout data:

```
// write out info to the display window
private static void shell_OutputDataReceived(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    string s = e.Data;

    if ((s != null) && (shellOut != null))
    {
        SomeOutOrLog(s);         //  output or log the string to somewhere
        shellOut.WriteLine(s);
    }
}

private static void shell_ErrorDataReceived(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    string s = e.Data;

    if (s != null) 
    {
        SomeOutOrLog(s);   //  output or log the string to somewhere
    }
}
```